# How to read data from USB port using C

Tags: c, usb

I have sensor node connected to USB port that sense temperature, humidity and light and send the data to PC.
What piece of code will help me to read that data from the USB port in normal **C**.
Application of the nodes is built on **C** using Eclipse.

Comment: Depends.  What operating system will this application be running on?  Operating systems all handle USB input differently.  Essentially, search for `serial communication`.

Comment: Can you list the the name and model number of the device, it will help a lot in figuring out what you need.

Comment: If the device does not implement a USB serial or virtual com port type of interface, the details of interacting with it will be more complicated.  `libusb` is a library that can give you a fairly consistent programming model across of all of Linux, Windows, and OSX, paving over many of the differences in their native USB APIs.

Comment: @BLaZuRE My application will be running on windows 7

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The device name is Jennic Evaluation kit JN5148

Answer (score 3):

I looked into the specifications of your board and it seems like it's a FTDI chip. This means it's exactly the same way you read from a serial port.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx) is how you program the serial port in Windows (it hasn't changed in a long time).

Comment: *Only* if the device implements a USB-serial or Virtual Com Port type of interface.  A lot of devices do, but it's far from the only possibility.

Comment: I agree with you but it was the most likely case.